# MySQL: Update column values by values from from other table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, inner-join

There is 2 MySQL tables as:

```
table1
id   name   phone

table2
id   phone
```

The record count > 20 billions.

How to update table1.phone by values from table2.phone where table1.id = table2.id?

My version is :

```
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.64-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

Comment: Does `id` in `table2` is unique? *The record count > 20 billions.* In **each** table?

Comment: Akina,yes is is uniq in tabl1 and table2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to want the `update ... join` syntax:

```
update table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.id = t.id
set t1.phone = t2.phone
```